# SAP Fiori Get logged in user details in UI5 application

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide, sap-business-technology-platform

I've a SAP Fiori application and I need to get the current logged in user details.
I've searched web but unable to find a solution.

is there any way to get current logged in user details from launchpad.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`UserInfo`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ushell.services.UserInfo) service from the FLP shell which can be retrieved like this:

```js
{ // In Controller
  doSomethingUserDetails: async function() {
    const userInfo = await this.getUserInfoService();
    const userId = userInfo.getId(); // And since 1.86: .getEmail(), .getFirstName(), .getLastName(), .getFullName(), ... 
    // ...
  },
  
  getUserInfoService: function() {
    return new Promise(resolve => sap.ui.require([
      "sap/ushell/library" // In the future, "sap/ushell/Container" might need to be required instead. Refer to API reference.
    ], sapUshellLib => {
      const Container = sapUshellLib.Container;
      const service = Container.getServiceAsync("UserInfo"); // .getService is deprecated!
      resolve(service);
    }));
  },
}
```

To align with the current best practices, **avoid** calling `sap.ushell.Container.getService` directly! Use [`getServiceAsync`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ushell.services.Container%23methods/getServiceAsync) instead.

**Alternatively:** information about the the current user can be also retrieved via the [*user API* service](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8c8e1958338140699bd4811b37b82ece/Cloud/en-US/ba8e562216de4faab94ba7982b225327.html) exposed by the application router from the SAP Business Technology Platform (SAP BTP).

---

* In case the app is deployed to the old *Neo* environment, see the [previous edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63524439/2).

Comment: Does this code snippet work for CloudFoundry deployment as well?

Comment: @ramanareddy438 Should work in CF environment as well. Try it let us know :)

Comment: @Hoffmann - This is not working in CF. I found a different approach for CF.

Comment: @ramanareddy438 Have you also tried the _User API service_ mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Yes. I have tried User API Service mentioned in the answer. But It did not work for me.

Comment: @Hoffmann: What approach did you use to get the login details on Cloud Foundry environment?

Comment: @ramanareddy438 Which approach did you find that has worked for you? If It's not working based on the above `UserInfo` API, please [create a customer support](https://me.sap.com/getsupport) to inform the FLP developers on CF about the not working API.

Comment: @MayankSaxena I believe it's an issue in FLP on CF unless it's documented otherwise that FLP doesn't support `UserInfo` API on CF.

Answer (score 0):

The User-ID can be retrieved from SDK.
Please refer to [class sap.ushell.services.UserInfo](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ushell.services.UserInfo/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new sap.ushell.services.UserInfo().getId()
```

Comment: API reference explicitly warns NOT to call the constructor directly: "[new ...] must be called by the Unified Shell's container only, others MUST call `sap.ushell.Container.getServiceAsync("UserInfo")`." Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63524439/5846045

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the user detail when you are running your application in launchpad. then you can retrieve current user detail by adding following code snippet:

```
var userInfo = sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo");
var email = userInfo.getEmail();
```

Then further detail about the user can be retrieved like email and fullname. See the API [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ushell.services.UserInfo/overview).